# Does numbering survey questions affect survey completion?

Tags: best-practice, surveys, questionnaire

Does displaying the number of the question in front of the question on a survey affect completion rates in any way?

E.g.,

1. Lorem ipsum?
2. Dolor sit amet?
3. Consectetur adipiscing elit?

vs.

Lorem ipsum?

Dolor sit amet?

Consectetur adipiscing elit?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe adding numbers to the question will affect completion rates.

But I do believe that it is good practice to show a progress bar or some sort of indication of how long or how many questions/pages there are in total.

This will let the user feel like they are making progress.

Some references to consider:

https://www.surveymonkey.com/mp/survey-guidelines/

https://optinmonster.com/survey-best-practices/

https://blog.hubspot.com/service/survey-design

Answer (score 0):

It is ok to number questions in the demographics question section. For example, you could say - 'Please answer the following 9 demographics question', and number the question.

However, when asking questions related to a construct (e.g., customer experience, satisfaction), which are measured with 3-6 rating questions - the questions should be randomised. Because these questions should be randomized, they should not have a serial number.

This Qualtrics article discusses survey question randomization: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/block-options/question-randomization/

This online article discusses why survey questions should be randomized https://help.alchemer.com/help/randomize-questions

Also, this journal article offers a good example of multiple large surveys with randomized questions (see the web appendix as well for procedural details) https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jretai.2022.03.003

Answer (score 0):

You could number the first one like- this question is number 1/30. Then number all of them

Comment: And why do you prefer that? What of the other options?

Comment: It gives a user a sense of the overall context that there are 30 questions. Secondly, then the number of the question indicates how close they are to completion, giving the user a sense of where they are